# What insect is in the PHP bugs logo?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Well, maybe this is a question more suited to Stack Overflow, but anyway, I am curious, **which insect is the one in the logo of the [PHP bugs site](https://bugs.php.net/)**? Is it an actual insect or just a generic "bug"?

[image]

It seems like some kind of [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera) for me, probably some kind of "true bug". A quick google search about these insects and I found the Hemiptera suborder [Heteroptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera), and this critter is probably from this group.

I tried to search by the image in google images, but only found the logo itself, in the same low resolution is the image above (I was not able to find a better version of it). I tried to remove the background from the image then, but still I didn't get any photo of the possible species of this logo.

**EDIT:** this was the PHP bugs logo up until [24th July 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170725102503/https://bugs.php.net/); the [next day](https://web.archive.org/web/20170726104739/https://bugs.php.net/) it was changed to another different "bug". This question is about the former logo, not the current one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an actual insect, *Lethocerus americanus*, also known as **Giant Water Bug**. See:

[image: Giant Water Bug (Lethocerus americanus) - London, Ontario 01.jpg from Wikicommons]

Matches the colors, body shape and small eyes and head. And yes, they are very annoying. As expected from real bugs. You know, [like the first one](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/thisday/sep9/worlds-first-computer-bug/).

Answer (score 3):

Most probably it is Boxelder bug, since their other logo clearly depicts it as seen [here](https://www.techworm.net/2014/10/php-bug-allows-integer-overflow-unserialize-php-patch-re.html)

As per [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxelder_bug)

> The boxelder bug (Boisea trivittata) is a North American species of true bug.
>   Trivittata is from the Latin tri (three) + vittata (banded).
>   Their congregation habits and excreta can annoy people; for this reason, they are considered nuisance pests.

[image]

Comment: Really, this bug is pretty similar to the one in my logo; the only difference I am seeing is the red coloration, but this can be a graphic design adjust for the logo; unhappily I was not able to find a better resolution version of that logo to compare the details...

Comment: Very light orange like coloration can be seen at back of insect in that logo too. Se their other logo which  clearly shows that insect

Comment: yes, you are right, in the other logo the coloration is pretty clear; I'll wait a bit if another answer comes, but I think this is the correct one. Thanks!